# Shutdown on pressing "SUPER + L", instead of Lock Screen

Tags: 18.04

As the title says, I am trying to lock screen with "SUPER + L", however, it's shutting down my machine.

It used to work before, but lately, I have started using an external monitor with my laptop(HDMI cable), and it has started happening since then.

Any thoughts?

UBUNTU:18.04

Answer (score 2):

Not sure about <kbd>SUPER</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> but you can try it. In my case it's works with another custom Shortcut:

- Go to Settings (Type **settings** in app menu search box)
- Go to in Settings -> Device -> Keyboard (or type **keyboard** in settings search)
- Scroll down all Keyboard Shortcuts and click "+" (add)
- In the new modal window in **Name** field type for example - `Shutdown`, In field **Command** type `shutdown -h now`, click **Set Shortcut...** and type <kbd>SUPER</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> or another Shortcut.

Done.